# Telegram Bot and Custom client

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I would like know if I can use Bot (taken from the Telegram Bot store) in a custom telegram client

I think so but I didn't found documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can use any bot from any client that support Telegram protocol.